# findNearest, findInRange - How to use in Screeps?

Tags: javascript, screeps

I try to use findNearest like that:

```
var sources = creep.room.findNearest(Game.SOURCES) 
creep.moveTo(sources[0]);
creep.harvest(sources[0]);
```

and this is what i get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at module.exports:5:28
at <main>:11:6
```

How to use this method and findInRange so that they don't cause this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several things to note here:

1. `findNearest()` is not in the room object. Simple fix `var sources = creep.pos.findNearest(Game.SOURCES)`
2. `findNearest()` does not return an array of objects, it returns one single object (specifically the closest object) or `null`. The fix here is to change what you have to `creep.moveTo(sources);` (you might want to make `sources` singular to avoid confusion)
3. You didn't provide code but I'm going to guess you're doing something like `creep.room.findInRange()` and again it's not in the room object it's in pos so it would look like this instead, `creep.pos.findInRange()`.
4. Confusingly, the only functions in room are `find()`, `lookAt()`, `findPath()`, and `makeSnapshot()` whereas pos has quite a few more (listed in roomposition in the docs)

If you look in the documentation [here](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php) for room and [here](http://screeps.com/docs/RoomPosition.php) for roomposition and scroll to the bottom you can see which functions are in which object.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see documentation has been updated and now has some sample code.

http://screeps.com/docs/RoomPosition.php

Comment: Please include the content you are linking directly in your answer; links rot.